# Open pdf in tar.gz without extracting

Tags: command-line, tar

I have a tar.gz which have pdfs in it I want to open a specific pdf without extracting it Is this possible using terminal through some command (I know we can do it using GUI but I want to use terminal)

Comment: GUI apps also stores as temporary files at `$HOME/.cache/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To list (not-open) files in archive without extracting, run following command:

```
tar -tf myarchive.tar.gz
```

To extract and open directly run following command:

```
tar -xzf myarchive.tar.gz && evince *.pdf
```

---

**For quick process:** (extacted in `/tmp/mypdf` and then removed)

```
mkdir /tmp/mypdf && tar -xzf myarchive.tar.gz -C /tmp/mypdf && cd /tmp/mypdf && evince *.pdf && cd .. && rm -r mypdf
```

Where `myarchive.tar.gz` is your sample archive name.

---

**For extracting specific file**,

```
mkdir /tmp/mypdf && tar -xzf myarchive.tar.gz -C /tmp/mypdf "<file.pdf>" && cd /tmp/mypdf && evince *.pdf && cd .. && rm -r mypdf
```

where `"<file.pdf>"` is file-name of that specific file you want to extract & open.

Hope it is helpful. *For advance function scripted command is useful by running script for specific purpose.*

Comment: For quick create and delete is added last.

Comment: Thanks Sir It worked as I wanted Can you explain what does -C mean?

Comment: your solution is extracting all files isn't there a way that it extracts only the file which I want to view I tried adding file name after tar file name but It was not getting extracted

Comment: @GauravDalpatyan : I added last option for only specific file where `<file.pdf>` is name of file which you want to open.

Comment: From `tar --help` ->`-x, --extract, --get       extract files from an archive`. Op wants to open a file in `tar.gz` archive without extracting it.

Comment: You can use `/tmp` instead of a new folder. That is what the GUI uses as well.

Comment: @far_sight : Ok. I edited and used `/tmp/mypdf/` as temporary directory, see edited answer.

Comment: And you forget to edit this `rm -r mypdf`

Comment: `cd .. && rm -r mypdf` part is not necessary. Files or folders in `/tmp` would be deleted automatically upon next reboot.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : I used this because without reboot, if user want to use this command again (may be for another archive) , then older files deleted and only newer files opens.

Answer (score 4):

To do this in a single command line, you need a pdf viewer which can handle input from a pipe. The only viewer with this option I know is ImageMagicks's **display**. It is not very comfortable (larger files may take a while), but may be it is convenient for your purpose.

```
tar xOfz <archive> <path/to/file/in/archive> | display
```

(Larger pdf files may take a while.)

Comment: Sorry tried installing imagemagick but returned with error code 1 Well I think it might work

Comment: Finally able to install but it hanged after loading a page

Comment: From `tar --help` ->`-x, --extract, --get       extract files from an archive`. Op wants to open a file in `tar.gz` archive without extracting it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj There is no way to process a file without extraction from its archive. In my case no file needs to be written (see Golboth's comment).

Comment: Why you failed to mention this in your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Opening without extracting is not possible. GUI applications are extracting the files temporarily before opening them...

If you have one tar.gz file containing PDF files, and you wish to extract one or more files using command line, you can use:

```
tar -xzf MyArchive.tar.gz MyPDF5.pdf

tar -xzf MyArchive.tar.gz MyPDF6.pdf MyPDF3.pdf

tar -xzf MyArchive.tar.gz "My PDF 128.pdf"
```

You can also extract one file from a folder in the archive (the directory structure will be kept):

```
tar -xzf MyArchive.tar.gz "My Archive Folder/My Other PDF.pdf"
```

If you don't wish to keep the directory structure, you can use --strip-components followed by the level of the subfolder:

```
tar -xzf MyArchive.tar.gz "My Archive Folder/My Other PDF.pdf" --strip-components 1

tar -xzf MyArchive.tar.gz "e-Books/Favorites/Ubuntu Linux/My PDF about Ubuntu.pdf" --strip-components 3
```

Please note that your archive file name must also be double-quoted if it contains spaces.

In the examples above, I'm supposing that you are in the folder containing the archive file and that you wish to extract there.

Before using tar command, you should use "cd" command to go to the folder in which you wish to extract the files. If the archive is located in another folder, simply put its absolute full path ["/home/myusername/Desktop/My Folder/My Other Archive.tar.gz"] (using a relative path may also be useful in some cases).

P.S.: If it was a simple text file (txt), "-O" parameter at the end of the command might have been what you were searching for, but since it is a PDF one, it is not very useful... According to [TAq answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/468169/28216), "display" from ImageMagick is able to handle that PDF output the way you wish with a pipe.

```
tar -xzf MyArchive.tar.gz "My PDF 128.pdf" -O | display
```

Comment: From `tar --help` ->`-x, --extract, --get       extract files from an archive`. Op wants to open a file in `tar.gz` archive without extracting it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's why I stated that "Opening without extracting is not possible" and that "GUI applications are extracting the files temporarily before opening them". Even with the parameter "-O" which allows to extract to the standard output, tar is still extracting, but not as a file on disk, which is somewhat closer to the initial goal of Gaurav Dalpatyan.

Comment: I didn't see that so +1.